# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'URL'

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, url

I have an array of image URL. And in my view did load i am showing in to my image view by passing some index values.

```
var studentImageURL = [URL]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   if let imageUrl = self.imageURLs[4] {

     }
}
```

In my if let i am getting `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'URL'`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: to check if image url is exist or not only i added if let.

Comment: Documentation for [Array subscript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1540606-subscript)

Comment: Just use let imageUrl = self.imageURLs[4]

Comment: We should be very clear here. There is no Optional in this story, so there is no usage for `if let` which is only about Optionals. To fetch an element from an array, just fetch it: `let imageUrl = self.imageURLs[4]`. But you will crash if there are not five elements in the array. You cannot avoid that by playing with Optionals; there are no Optionals here. If your goal is to avoid the crash, just say first `guard self.imageURLs.count > 4 {else return}` (or something similar to that), so that you don't try to use a non-existent index.

Answer (score 0):

Your param "studentImageUrl" is and array which consists of URL unoptional! params.
if you want to add the protection level you can do the following:

```
var studentImageURL = [URL?]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if studentImageURL.count > 4 {
        if let imageUrl = self.studentImageURL[4] {

        }
    }
}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: why not? its usually better for URL object to be optional since its initialiser returns optional value

Comment: fair enough, i wanted to show him a correct and more cleaner way of executing what i think he wanted to accomplish. thanks for the heads up about the params miss match

Comment: A URL may be optional, but you would usually not store optional URLs in an array.

Answer (score 0):

"if let" is used to check whether an optional value is nil or not. It can *only* be used for optional values. self.imageURLs[4] is a URL, not an optional URL.

Just use "let" instead of "if let".